# Adding different effects to Bootstrap Carousel

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

After searching through the internet, I found out two different effect that we could apply on Bootstrap Carousel namely, Slide and Fade. Are there any other effect like splitting the picture into small 3d boxes that turn around to change the image or similar?

Answer (score 0):

try this plugin for performance and change the css animation the way you want it[here](https://medium.com/@haydenbleasel/enhancing-bootstrap-carousel-performance-with-css3-29bfb20d1324)

https://gist.github.com/haydenbleasel/8158640